# Error with JQuery attribute checked

Tags: jquery, variables, checkbox

For some reason this is not working. Instead it thinks it should check the checkbox rather than find out if the box is checked. Can anyone see where I have gone wrong.

```
if ($('#OPT2checked').attr('checked','checked')) {
    var OPT2checked = 'checked="checked"';
    } else {var OPT2checked = ''};
```

Any ideas?

Marvellous,

Comment: Have you tried reading the [documentation for `.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr#attr2)? It defines the second parameter clearly: *"A value to set for the attribute."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :)

```
 if ($('#OPT2checked').is(':checked')) {
     // Your thing
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('#OPT2checked').attr('checked','checked')` sets the attribute 'checked' to 'checked'

`$('#OPT2checked').attr('checked')` returns the value of the checked attribute.

By the way, you should test if the checked attribute is defined and not if it has a specific value.